# Can't connect to Docker container running MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, docker

The Docker run command is:

docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=flurpgraSS -d mysql:5.7

Docker Desktop shows the container:
[image]
I can access the server from the CLI launched by Docker Desktop and the root account appears to be OK:
[image]

I can't access the server using MySQL Workbench
[image]

Comment: Could you show us docker run command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We might need to expose port from docker by `-p` parameter, otherwise, we can't access it outside.

```
docker run --name some-mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Danger42! -d mysql:5.7
```

There is some description from [Container networking](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)

> -p 3306:3306：Map TCP port 3306 in the container to port 3306 on the Docker host.

Comment: When I start the image I get this error "Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."

Comment: @nicomp The port of 3306 might be used from your host computer

Comment: There is another sample, we can change the left of port parameter  ex: `-p 5555:3306` we can connect the MySQL container by `5555` from your host

Comment: That was the problem. The service was already running on the desktop. Thanks!